# Dealing with multipart responses

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

I'm playing with Amazon Alexa (AVS) and the service mostly sends multipart responses.
For example a response can contain an application/json part associated with an application/octet-stream (MP3 data) part.

For now I don't have any idea the way to write my Retrofit2 service method for it to handle it correctly.
I guess an `AlexaMultiPartResponse` object here won't work:

```
@Multipart
@Post("/path")
Call<AlexaMultiPartResponse> getAnswer(@Part("metadata") RequestBody metadata, @Part("audio") RequestBody audio);
```

Do you have any idea?

Regards.

Comment: I posted you some answer you might take a look at.

Answer (score 0):

According to this: https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/2164 there is no elegant way to do it with Retrofit2.

So I ended up parsing the multipart response with Apache FileUpload MultipartStream (https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/MultipartStream.html)

Comment: I am really curious how you were able parse a multipartstream since i am not able to create the correct contstructor for it. See my question 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44634316/issues-with-multipartstream-progressnotifier-constructor

Comment: I don't use MultipartStream.ProgressNotifier so I pass null. I can't help you, sorry.